# css "vertical for-loop" - helper for css grid - string repeat/build

Tags: css, loops, sass, postcss

if you heard about css grid, maybe you stumbled on the same issue:

i'm trying to build a for loop with postcss to build something like this for easy class usage in my page (to keep it simple i left out -ms- support here, where i have to build similar stuff, but with calculations)

```
.ac-grid--even-1 {

        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }


.ac-grid--even-2 {

        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }


.ac-grid--even-3 {

        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
```

my only problem here is... how the heck can i repeat horizonal stuff like
1fr 1fr 1fr ? was looking for packages and stuff but wasnt able to find something usefull :< i'm looking for something like:

```
  .ac-grid--even {

    @for $grid_number from 1 to 12 {
   &-$grid_number {

        grid-template-columns: $grid_number * '1fr ';
   }
    }
   }
```

Thank you

---

edit:

Thanks to Terry

For postcss its just a little bit different, if someone needs it:

```
    $incrementalFr: 1fr;
    @for $grid_number from 1 to 12 {
        .ac-grid--even-$grid_number {

            grid-template-columns: $incrementalFr;
        }
        $incrementalFr: $incrementalFr 1fr;
    }
```

---

edit2: this way don't work with calculations :/

example:

```
    $incrementalFr: 1fr;
    $test: ;
    @for $grid_number from 1 to 12 {
        $col: $grid_number;
        $spacer: ($col - 1);
        $test: $test calc((100% / $col) - (($grid-gap * $spacer) / $col)) $grid-gap;

        &-$grid_number {
            -ms-grid-columns: $test;
            grid-template-columns: $incrementalFr;
        }
        $incrementalFr: $incrementalFr 1fr;
    }
```

which makes sense since it just adds one part at a time, what results in a "correct" length of the string but with increasing numbers instead of repeated blocks ^^

damn you IE !!!

any other suggestions? workarounds? packages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic in SASS:

1. Declare a variable that starts with `1fr`, e.g. `$incrementalFr: #{"1fr"};`
2. Use a `@for` loop and loop through 1 to 13 (13 is not included, so you will have 12 classes in total).
3. In each loop, declare the class and assigned it the variable: `grid-template-columns: $incrementalFr;`
4. At the end of each iteration, you append `1fr` to the variable (so that `1fr` is repeated once more in the next iteration), using `append($incrementalFr, #{"1fr"})`

Here is the SASS code ([check out the compiled CSS](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/36e2e5a0f80e0e0a5a54eb3cd98dce91)):

```
$incrementalFr: #{"1fr"};

@for $grid_number from 1 to 13 {
  .ac-grid--even-#{$grid_number} {
      grid-template-columns: $incrementalFr;
  }
  $incrementalFr: append($incrementalFr, #{"1fr"});
}
```

The compiled CSS (truncated for brevity) looks like this:

```
.ac-grid--even-1 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.ac-grid--even-2 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.ac-grid--even-3 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

// ...
// Lines are truncated for brevity
// ...

.ac-grid--even-12 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: sorry, its an awesome solution for that easy 1fr part but grabs me by the balls with calculations ;/